# Maven 3 different profiles - Spring propertyPlaceHolderConfig cannot use value from pom file

Tags: spring, maven-3

I'm having some problems with maven 3 and getting to load the right .properties file.

What I want to achieve is the following: With mvn -Plocal i want to load the setting-local.properties, and if its run with prod i want to load the settings-prod.properties.

It works by using mvn -Denv=local, but when I try with the -Plocal the variable are not loaded (settings-${env}.properties does not exist).

My pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>local</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In my applicationcontext I have want to load the env-variable:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
                <list>
                        <value>classpath:settings-${env}.properties
                        </value>
                </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders">
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

So whats the problem, should'nt it work both ways?

Comment: Allright, so I finally found out what the problem was in my example. I had an @ annotation in the application context, so even when I used filtering it did not work until I either removed the annotations or escaped string by using http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing Spring's [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) with [Maven's Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) mechanism.  These are similar but completely separate mechanisms (but they can be used together).

- Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer allows you to acquire values from a properties file for use inside your Spring application context.
- Maven's filtering allows you to replace values in text files (including properties files) with values from your Maven properties and environment.

You can combine them but then it becomes a two stage process.  Your Maven build uses filtering to put values in your properties files and then in turn this can be read by Spring.  *Confused? (I am)*

Comment: Thanks for clearing up a little, and make me take an extra look into it. Was confusing yeah, but problem with my way was an @ in the applicationcontext that made it not work. By escapeString it worked. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html

Answer (score 2):

Maven Project Properties are not System Properties, so this won't work out of the box.

One thing you could do is use [Maven Resource Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to replace property keys in your Spring Context file. Or, even better, have a property file that you filter and reference that from Spring.

Comment: What I want to do, and have also tried without success is to use the filtering to replace the ${env} variable, but it seems like the applicationcontext.xml will not be filtered/replaced. Do you have any solutions to this?